# How do I add one event to all textboxes?

Tags: c#

I made this physics calculator where I type in the acceleration and mass, for example, and it gives me the force. Now I came across 2 problems:

1) The current event is a mouse click, but I think having the answer pop up in a TextChanged event would be better. The thing is, I have around 9 textboxes and I don't think I want to add the same huge if statement to every single textbox event. How do I add this huge pile of code into every textbox without having to add an event to every single one?

2) My current method of doing things is checking if each textbox is null a number of times for each "formula". Which means I have the same formula getting repeated 3 times just because it gets written differently
For example:
F = ma
could be written as F/m = a which takes in another else if statement till it fills all the formulas. Is there a way I could make it briefer than what it currently is? Because right now I have to right this in front of every if statement:

```
        else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxAcc.Text) &&
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxFg.Text) &&
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxFn.Text) &&
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxF.Text) &&
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxFk.Text) &&
            !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxMass.Text) &&
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxUk.Text) &&
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxVi.Text) &&
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxVf.Text) &&
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxTime.Text) &&
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxD.Text) &&
            String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBoxFnet.Text))
```

Comment: For the first question, can't you just define a method and on every textbox event just call that method, instead of repeat the code everytime?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the same method in the event handler of TextChanged in all text boxes as following:

```
 private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

 txtBoxFg.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
 txtBoxFn.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
 txtBoxF.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
 txtBoxFk.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
 txtBoxMass.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
 txtBoxUk.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
 txtBoxVi.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
 txtBoxVf.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
 txtBoxTime.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
 txtBoxD.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
 txtBoxFnet.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Avoid handling a similar event at different positions in your code. Since you only deal with text-boxes it's very straight forward to do all your calculations in a single text-changed event-handler.

Just link it to every text-changed-event unsing +=

Answer (score 0):

Define an event handler to use more than once:

```
EventHandler handler = (s, e) => {
   var textBox = s as TextBox;
   if (textBox == null)
      return;

   // handle event
};
```

Simple way to get all text boxes, except that it won't search within container controls:

```
Controls
.OfType<TextBox>()
.ToList()
.ForEach(textBox => textBox.TextChanged += handler);
```

Or a little more complicated way to get at all controls in the hierarchy:

```
var visited = new HashSet<Control>();

// tricky way to have a recursive lambda
Action<Control, Action<Control>> visitRecursively = null;
visitRecursively = (control, visit) => {
   // duplicate control test might be unnecessary
   // but avoids infinite recursion or duplicate events
   if (visited.Contains(control))
      return;
   visited.Add(control);

   visit(control);

   control
   .Controls
   .Cast<Control>()
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(subControl => visitRecursively(subControl, visit));
};

Action<Control> addMyHandler = control => {
   TextBox textBox = control as TextBox;
   if (textBox != null)
      textBox.TextChanged += handler;
};

visitRecursively(this, addMyHandler);
```